# Checking if a string contains a particular word

Tags: c#, combobox, string-matching

I want to put all the words that DO NOT contain the word "Time" in a combobox.

I tried :

```
foreach (string stt in LTypes)
{
    //if the stat name does not contains TIME
    //Only then we add it to the combobox.

    if (!stt.Contains("Time"))
    { 
        tcomboBox1.Items.Add(stt);    
    }
}
```

But the above does not works.
By does not work I mean that the words containing "Time" also is being inserted in the combobox.

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: I think you forget to mention that these are not cased the same way. Am I wrong? `Time` is not the same as `time`.

Comment: Is that single place where you fill combobox? Also can you provide sample strings with `Time` which are added?

Comment: What is `LTypes`? What happens when you run the above code?

Comment: LTypes is evidently a IEnumerable collection of string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a casing issue.

Try this:

```
if (!stt.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("TIME"))
```

This will work regardless of case.

Answer (score 2):

For what we can see from your code and your issue description, either the match fails (due to different case) or your combobox gets populated over and over.

Try this:

```
//remember to clear your combobox if it is already populated!
tcomboBox1.Items.Clear(); 
foreach (string stt in LTypes)
{
    //setting string to lower/upper case will let you match any occurence of your word
    if (!stt.ToLowerCase().Contains("time"))
    { 
        tcomboBox1.Items.Add(stt);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IndexOf` with `StringComparision.OrdinalIngoreCase`

```
if (!(stt.IndexOf("Time", StringComparision.OrdinalIngoreCase) >=0))
```